# full one-dimensional array in a two-dimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to full one dimensional array in two dimensional array in Java.
I did it using this way, is there another way better than this?

```
public double[][] getResult(double[] data, int rowSize) {
    int columnSize = data.length;
    double[][] result = new double[columnSize][rowSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < columnSize; i++) {
        result[i][0] = data[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Edit:** i am not going to reuse **data**-Array i want to set the reference of first column in **result**-array to the **data**-array .is it possible? if yes, how can i do this ?

Comment: that looks fine to me

Comment: I don't understand, you want to convert a 1d array into a 2d array with a specific row size? What if the array length is not divisible by the row size? For example, you have a 1d array of length 16. You give a row size of 7. Elements 0-6 go in the first row, 7-13 in the second, 14-15 go in the third and you have 5 "empty" cells.

Comment: if the code is working you should post this at our stack member [codereview](codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: it is application requirement, i will do some operation in the 5 empty cells .

Comment: @davejal okay i will do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this makes sense in your application/context, but for performance reasons you should normally have **coherent data as close in the memory as possible**.
For Arrays (`double[row][column]`) that means that data which is has the same `row` value is normally stored very close in the memory. For example when you have an Array like `double[][] d = double[10][10]` and save two values like `d[0][0] = 1.0; d[1][0] = 2.0;`, then they are (I think) **40 bytes** away from each other.
But when you save them like `d[0][0] = 1.0; d[0][1] = 2.0;`, they're **directly next to each other** in the memory and are normally loaded into the super-fast cache at the same time. When you want to use them iteratively, then that is a huge performance gain.

So for your application, a first improvement would be this:

```
public double[][] getResult(double[] data, int rowSize) {
    int columnSize = data.length;
    double[][] result = new double[rowSize][columnSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < columnSize; i++) {
        result[0][i] = data[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Secondly, you have to consider whether you are going to re-use the `data`-Array or not. Because if you don't re-use it, you can just **set the reference** of the first row in your `result` Array **to the `data`-Array** like this:

```
result[0] = data;
```

Again, this gives you another huge performance gain.
Why? Well simply because you don't need to use unnecessary much memory by copying all values - and as you might know, memory allocation can be rather slow.
So always re-use memory instead of copying it wildly.

So my full suggestion is to go with this code:

```
public double[][] getResult(double[] data, int rowSize) {
    double[][] result = new double[rowSize][];
    result[0] = data;
    return result;
}
```

It is optional whether you set the `columnSize` or not.

Comment: it is not possible to apply first point it is not suitable for my application , second point that is exactly what i want to do (i am not going to re-use data-Array) but i want to set the reference of first column (not row) in result array to the data-array .is it possible?if yes, how can i do this ? (i am going to update the question )

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible then.